# Why can’t I talk in voice chat on MK1 on Xbox?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, mortal-kombat-1-2023

My mic is being picked up in every game except for this one. I looked into audio settings and there’s no way to turn my mic on or off. I’ve looked up how to fix it but it’s mainly for window users. I can hear others but they can’t hear me. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sanity check, your microphone isn't physically muted right (like via a button on the headset/mic?)

Comment: @TimmyJim nope i can hear myself in my headset when i talk, but others can’t hear me at all but i can hear them